# Angular - Observable.catch does not fire returned observable

Tags: angular, http, ionic3, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I've got an application that displays a list of questions. When the app starts up, I want to check if we've got any questions stored, and if we don't, then we do a request to get the questions from the cloud.

I've got a simple function that returns a POST request:

```
getQuestions() {
   return this.http.post(AppSettings.CI_GET_QUESTIONS, '')
```

}

If I subscribe to this Observable:

```
this.dataService.getQuestions()
  .map(questions => questions.json())
  .map((questions) => {
    return questions;
  })
  .subscribe((success) => {
    console.log("### sc:", success)
  })
```

I get my array of questions printed out, so far so good.

However, I went to check if we already have the questions stored locally, and if we don't then go get the questions from the cloud. So I've wrote this Observable to do this:

```
this.storage.checkQuestionsLocally()
  .catch((error) => {
    return this.dataService.getQuestions()
      .map(questions => questions.json())
      .map((questions) => {
        return questions;
      })

  })
  .subscribe((done) => {
    console.log("### questions done:", done)
  }, (error) => {
    console.log("### error during getting questions:", error)
  }, () => {
    console.log("### questions found routine is completed");
  })
```

On startup we check do we have anything stored locally, and if we receive an error, then go get the questions.

The problem I'm having is in this `catch` function. The error triggers the `catch`, and the code attempts to execute the request but nothing actually happens. I can see on the Network page (of Chrome Dev Tools) that the request I have is cancelled:

`getQuestions (canceled)    xhr polyfills.js:3  0 B 15 ms`

Why is this being cancelled? Shouldn't the request just fire and bring the questions back?

Thanks,
bengrah

Comment: No request is made because you have no subscription to that.

Comment: So far in all the examples I've seen you don't need to subscribe to the Observable. if I passed in something like

`
.catch(error => { return Observable.of(3) }
`

This will display 3 on the console. I'll try it and come back to you

Comment: I get the following error adding a `.subscribe`

   Argument of type '(catchError: any) => Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<{}>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.